# Reading a JSON file in python and converting into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

the data in the JSON file is in the below format

```
{"data":{"process1":[{"time":"2012-01-02T20:13:56+00:00" , "value":"400.63"}, {"time":"2013-04-02T22:13:56+00:00" , "value":"800.43"}, {"time":"2013-06-02T21:13:56+00:00" , "value":"600.43"},{"time":"2014-07-02T21:13:56+00:00" , "value":"100.43"}],
"process2":[{"time":"2012-02-02T20:13:56+00:00" , "value":"50.63"}, {"time":"2013-05-06T22:13:56+00:00" , "value":"400.43"}]}}
```

Note that the number of Key,value pairs in process1(4) and process2(2) are different
And i want to convert the above data into below Python Pandas dataframe format
[Dataframe format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvChk.png)

Comment: ansev can you please give me all lines of code which you have executed to get this output. I am new to python. So facing problems here

Comment: of course, Solution updated! Is your json  a dict or str?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) + [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
json={"data":{"process1":[{"time":"2012-01-02T20:13:56+00:00" , "value":"400.63"}, {"time":"2013-04-02T22:13:56+00:00" , "value":"800.43"}, {"time":"2013-06-02T21:13:56+00:00" , "value":"600.43"},{"time":"2014-07-02T21:13:56+00:00" , "value":"100.43"}],
"process2":[{"time":"2012-02-02T20:13:56+00:00" , "value":"50.63"}, {"time":"2013-05-06T22:13:56+00:00" , "value":"400.43"}]}}
```

---

```
new_df=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(y).add_prefix(f'{x}_') for x,y in json['data'].items()],axis=1)
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output**

```
               process1_time process1_value              process2_time  \
0  2012-01-02T20:13:56+00:00         400.63  2012-02-02T20:13:56+00:00   
1  2013-04-02T22:13:56+00:00         800.43  2013-05-06T22:13:56+00:00   
2  2013-06-02T21:13:56+00:00         600.43                        NaN   
3  2014-07-02T21:13:56+00:00         100.43                        NaN   

  process2_value  
0          50.63  
1         400.43  
2            NaN  
3            NaN
```

---